# Finding a sequence of numbers in a multi dimensional list

Tags: search, multidimensional-array

How do I find if a sequence of numbers exists in a two-dimensional list? i.e.

```
    matrix:  [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

    if [1,1,1] in matrix:
        print("It's in there")
    else: print("It's not there")
```

I guess I could turn every int into a string but is there a slicker way?

Comment: Can you please tag the language? I don't recognize this but can offer pseudocode. Looks like Python, going to run some tests in that language. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iterator over each cell of the matrix, I've managed to get a basic idea of what you wanted to achieve in Python script.

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

matchCount = 0
lastNumber = None

for cell in matrix:
    for number in cell:
        if number == 1 and lastNumber == 1 or lastNumber == None:
            matchCount += 1
            if matchCount >= 3:
                print("MATCH in cell " + str(cell))
        lastNumber = number
    matchCount = 0
    lastNumber = None
```

What happens is, it steps into the cell. It it's the first iteration then allow entry into our iterator. We don't know if it's a match list yet, so push it back in our little list.

Stepping over and over, if we get enough matches in a row, then wonderful! Print we found a match in our matrix's cell!

Comment: Tested and tweaked using multiple variations in the matrix, no issues found.